# Extracting columns from textfile given some criteria - python

Tags: python, dictionary, csv

I have a tab delimited file as such:

```
0923    ar blah black sheep 5555    hahahaa
234.231 world
111.11 whatever whatever    123123
whatsoever
03241
```

I need to make it into dictionary structure where

- the 2nd column is the key
- the value is a tuple of the 1st and 3rd column
- anything with 1 column would not be in the dictionary
- anything outside of the 1st 3 columns are ignored

The desired output is:

```
{'ar blah black sheep': ('0923', '5555'), 'whatever whatever': ('111.11', '123123')}
```

I've been doing as such:

```
text = """0923  ar blah black sheep 5555    hahahaa
234.231 world
111.11  whatever whatever   123123
whatsoever  
03241"""

result = {}

for i in text.split('\n'):
    columns = i.strip().split('\t')
    if 1 < len(columns) and len(columns) > 2:
        result[columns[1]] = (columns[0], columns[2])

print result
```

**Is there another way of doing this?** Keep in mind that the number of lines in the textfile is beyond 2 million lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) is the best method.

import csv, sys

```
 with open("somefile.txt", 'r') as in_file:
      dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(in_file.read(1024)) # detect tab delimiter
      in_file.seek(0) 
      next(reader, none) # skip header
      reader = csv.reader(in_file, dialect) # load file with the determined delimiter
```

reader will be a dictionary format. You can use

```
 out_file = open("somefile2.txt", 'w')
 writer = csv.writer(out_file)
 for row in reader:
      writer.writerow(row)
 out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

For large files you can use `for line in file` this handles the loading for you and does not put the whole file into memory.

But for specific filetypes like tsv you can use the build-in module csv.
You just need to tell the csv module how your data is delimited.

```
import csv

with open("foo.tsv", "r") as f:
    reader= csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')   # tell csv to parse a tsv
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) >= 3:   # if we got atleast 3 arguments
            key, value = row[1], (row[0],row[2])    # set the 2nd as key the 1st and 3rd as value
            print('Key:"'+key+'" Value:'+str(value))
```

Comment: i doesn't capture the rows that only have 2 columns

Comment: @alvas I tried to recreate the desired output and this does not include 2 column rows.